# Postgresql can't copy JSON document

Tags: json, postgresql

I created a table by using Postgresql after that I tried to copy the json document inside of that table with:

```
\copy document_json FROM '/path/to/document.json';
```

However it gives an error such as: ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x9e in encoding "WIN1254" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
CONTEXT:  COPY document_json, line 1

I couldn't find any explanation for this error. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What is the encoding of your file?

Comment: `\copy` can only import CSV files or similar "flat files" with a delimiter between each column value where each line represents one row to be imported. If you expect `\copy` to turn your JSON key/value pairs automatically into column values then this won't happen.

Comment: Encoding is utf8 btw